# Programmatically insert a row in auth_user table in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

How to programmatically insert a row that includes email and and hashed password into auth_user in web2py? Something like the flask-compatible code below.

```
def find_or_create_user(username, email, password, role=None):
    """ Find existing user or create new user """
    user = User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(username=username,
                    email=email,
                    password=current_app.user_manager.hash_password(password),
                    is_enabled=True,
                    confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        if role:
            user.roles.append(role)
        db.session.add(user)
    return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material line is:

```
db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(email=email, password=password...)
```